# Can I bake licensed dependencies (i.e. software under GPL) into a Docker image and keep the project MIT-licensed?

Tags: licensing, dependencies, docker

I'm a little new to the nuances of how licensing of software can propagate/affect other pieces of software so sorry if there's anything in the question that doesn't make sense.

Basically though, I'm trying to package up some software that is MIT licensed that has dependencies that are mixed licensed (I think it's a couple GPL dependencies and some MIT/BSD dependencies) into a more easily deployable solution (Docker).

I see my options as:

1. Put commands for installing dependencies into the Dockerfile but have users build the image themselves (instead of pushing built images to an image repo). I think I've seen online that this is okay, but this isn't ideal for us because our clients won't always be familiar with Docker and how to run things themselves.
2. Write an install script and have it as a part of a container's startup process at runtime. This is okay for us, but it adds some overhead to spinning up new containers (which we'll be running as scalable workers, so this isn't ideal as they'll be coming up/winding down often).
3. Bake the dependencies into an image and push this image to a public image repository. This is ideal for us, but sounds closest to the language of "distribution", which is a bit spooky to me!

I guess I'm wondering, are there any differences from a licensing perspective between 2 and 3? If so, what are they? Will either 2 or 3 be incompatible with our desire to keep the source code for our binary MIT licensed? Are there other solutions that I've overlooked?

Comment: When you say *dependencies*, what do you mean?  Is the software linked to some libraries?

Comment: Nope - the container's Dockerfile likely contains something like "apt install readline" (to pick a random GPL-3 package). It's a really loose analogy but imagine they are distributing a VMWare appliance with GPL-3 stuff pre-installed.

Comment: @MadHatter the software calls out to the shell and runs the GPL licensed software from the command line (i.e. using subprocess.Popen in python). so the dependency is that the external software is installed in the local environment

Comment: @kdopen hmm okay so if I'm understanding you correctly, if in a Dockerfile I have "apt install readline", build that image, and push it to an image repository, that image will be GPL-3 licensed. what if the image had a bash script in the image that had the "apt install readline" command that ran at container runtime? does that make a difference?

Comment: What is "the project", exactly? Is it the Dockerfile? The Docker image?

Comment: @user253751 good question. we have a binary that can be installed from source (hosted on github) under an MIT license. to make it easier to for users to deploy this and use the binary themselves, we want to create a container for the binary that has dependencies pre-installed (or with a script to install into that container environment)

Comment: @joe Ah, your program has a GPL dependency? In the FSF's opinion, that makes your program a derivative work of the dependency. Even if it's dynamically linked. (And I'm not a copyright lawyer, but their interpretation makes some sense - your program is based on the APIs in the shared library, right?)

Comment: @user253751 it actually runs the GPL dependency from the shell (i.e. inside our software package, it ingests a config file that has a path to where the GPL binary lives on the machine, and calls that binary from the shell and ingests the output), so I'm not sure if that's the same or not?

Comment: @joe then the FSF's position is that it's not a derivative work. However, the Docker image still is, if it includes a copy of the program.